# Wget including/excluding directories

Tags: regex, wget

I cannot get what **wget** expects.

The directory looks like:

```
server:
> d1
-> d2
--> A
---> 2021
----> file_A_2021_1
----> file_A_2021_2
----> file_A_2021_3
---> 2022
----> file_A_2022_1
----> file_A_2022_2
----> file_A_2022_3
---> 2023
----> file_A_2023_1
----> file_A_2023_2
----> file_A_2023_3
--> B
---> 2021
----> file_B_2021_1
----> file_B_2021_2
----> file_B_2021_3
---> 2022
----> file_B_2022_1
----> file_B_2022_2
----> file_B_2022_3
---> 2023
----> file_B_2023_1
----> file_B_2023_2
----> file_B_2023_3
```

a) I want **wget** to exclude all 2021 and 2022 directories.

I can do it with:

`-X "/d1/d2/*/202[12]"`

But when the structure complicates a bit I start to get confused on which wildcards **wget** accepts and which it doesn't.

b) I want to include only

B/2021/file_B_2021_2
B/2021/file_B_2021_3
B/2023/file_B_2023_2
B/2023/file_B_2023_3

which I would shorten in naive regex to `B/202[13]/file_B_202[13]_[2-3]`. But I cannot get it in wget language.

The real life command I am using for case similar to a) and that works is something like:

`wget -v -nH -np -w1 --random-wait -r -N --cut-dirs=2 -e robots=off --reject-regex ".*htm.*,.*list.*" -A "file_*_2023_*" -X "/d1/d2/*/202[12]" --user myuser --password mypass ftp://mysever.com/d1/d2/`

What are the smartest (but still clearest) ways of using

```
-A
-R
-I
-X
--accept-regex
--reject-regex
or other...
```

to achieve a) an b) ?

Answer (score 0):

May be not the smartest but a kind-of-clear way could be the following. It works for downloading:

_ all files finishing in '_2': `-A "*file*202*2"`
_ from subdirs 'A' and 'B' including all subdirs in these two: `-I "/d1/d2/[AB]/,/d1/d2/*"`
_ avoiding the '.listing' file and any html file named as such: `-R "*htm*,*list*"`:

`wget -v -nH -np -w1 --random-wait -r -N --cut-dirs=2 -e robots=off -R "*htm*,*list*" -A "*file*202*2" -I "/d1/d2/[AB]/,/d1/d2/*" --user myuser --password mypass ftp://myserver.com/d1/d2/`

So a solution for b) above would be (not tested):

`wget -v -nH -np -w1 --random-wait -r -N --cut-dirs=2 -e robots=off -R "*htm*,*list*" -A "*file_B_*_[23]" -I "/d1/d2/B/,/d1/d2/B/202[13]/" --user myuser --password mypass ftp://myserver.com/d1/d2/`